# ASP.NET MVC Custom Routing Long Custom Route not Clicking in my Head

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have spent several hours today reading up on doing Custom Routing in ASP.NET MVC. I can understand how to do any type of custom route if it expands from or is similar/smaller than the Default Route. However, I am trying figure out how to do a route similar to:

```
/Language/{LanguageID}/Question/{QuestionID}/
```

And what I would like, too, is similar to how SO works. Something like:

```
/Language/{LanguageID}/Arabic/Question/{QuestionID}/Some-Question-Title
```

Where "Arabic" and "Some-Question-Title" can be almost anything because what really matters is the ID's

A complete url example might be

```
http://example.com/Language/22/Arabic/Question/135/What-is-the-importance-of-grammar
```

Am I going beyond what can be done with the extended URL past the language ID?

Comment: Should "id" be two separate IDs?  Eg. A language id and a question id?

Comment: yes. I was trying to keep it "simple", but I'll ed it to better reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty much do anything with routes, but the key is knowing in which order to register them.  When MVC selects a route, it does so in order in which they were registered, and the first route that matches, is the one that is selected.