# ASP.NET MVC 2 Routing with additional consistent parameters (not just controller & action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

Currently, I have URLs that look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/user/create
http://www.example.com/user/edit/1
```

But now, I have to support multiple organizations and their users. I need to have something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/org-name/user/create
http://www.example.com/org-name/user/edit/1
```

I was having trouble getting the routes to work just perfectly, so I had to add a token to the beginning of the organization name so that routing wouldn't confuse it with a controller/action pair. Not a huge deal but my URLs look like this now:

```
http://www.example.com/o/org-name/user/create
http://www.example.com/o/org-name/user/edit/1
```

That's fine. I can live with that.

**Here's where I'm running into trouble:**
When I generate URLs once I have an organization selected, it's not persisting the organization name. So when I'm here:

```
http://www.example.com/o/org-name
```

...and I use Url.Action("User", "Create") to generate a URL, it outputs:

```
/user/create
```

...rather than what I want:

```
/o/org-name/user/create
```

This is what my routes look like (in order):

```
        routes.MapRouteLowercase(
            "DefaultOrganization",
            "{token}/{organization}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { token = "o" }
        );

        routes.MapRouteLowercase(
            "OrganizationDashboard",
            "{token}/{organization}/{controller}",
            new { controller = "Organization", action = "Dashboard" },
            new { token = "o" }
        );

        routes.MapRouteLowercase(
            "DefaultSansOrganization",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Core", action="Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It's similar to this question [ASP.NET MVC Custom Routing Long Custom Route not Clicking in my Head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982140/asp-net-mvc-custom-routing-long-custom-route-not-clicking-in-my-head).

I have a feeling this is going to end up being obvious but it's Friday and it's not happening right now.

**EDIT:**
Womp's suggested worked but would this be the best way to automate this?

```
public static string ActionPrepend(this UrlHelper helper, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        string currentUrl = helper.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["url"] as string;
        string actionUrl = string.Empty;

        if (currentUrl != null)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(currentUrl);

            if (url.Segments.Length > 2 && url.Segments[1] == "o/")
                actionUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", url.Segments[0], url.Segments[1], url.Segments[2],
                    helper.Action(actionName, controllerName));
        }

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionUrl))
            actionUrl = helper.Action(actionName, controllerName);

        return actionUrl;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Fixed my routes to work rather than hacking it together. The final solution didn't need the stupid {token} in the URL. Maybe this'll help someone else:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
    "Organization",
    "{organization}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Organization", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { organization = @"^(?!User|Account|Report).*$" }
);

routes.MapRouteLowercase(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Core", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321750/advanced-asp-net-mvc-routing-scenario Wouldn't it make more sense to store the Organization in the session rather than in the route? How will you authenticate that your users don't try to access other organizations?

Comment: If you ask me, I don't like your solution of a token in the first place. Organization name is a parameter just as an ID of a user is.
You are editing John Doe with an ID of 1 and from organization Contoso. I would just add the organization parameter at the end or in the middle of your route like this: {controller}/{action}/{organization}/{id}. I would actually define the routes more specific for instance, for create User/Create/{organization} or for edit User/Edit/{organization}/{id}. Either way using organization in there is only necessary if you use OrgID and UserID as composite primary key

Comment: @Ryan we're running on Azure so I'd have to keep all of the session information in a cookie (not terrible). Our API already enforces security at each call, so people guessing other organization names (or having duplicates in different accounts) is addressed.

Comment: @mare you're right, token was a stupid idea :) I managed to fix the routes to allow for what I was trying to accomplish! I'll update the code in the original question with my final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url.Action uses route values to generate the actual URL's by querying the virtual path provider and attempting to match the most specific route.  In the form that you are using, you are supplying values for the controller and the action, which is as deep as most simple websites go, hence the convenient form of the method.  When Url.Action queries the routing system, it only has a "controller" and an "action" segment to match.

If you give the method the rest of the routing information it needs, it will properly match the route that you desire, and will return the correct URL.  Try this:

```
Url.Action("User", "Create", new { token = "o", organization = "organization" })
```

Comment: Ah ha, that worked!

So to automate this, would a extension method on UrlHelper be best? I edited the question above with the code that works.