# Can MVC handle regular URL path requests, too?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

ASP.NET MVC newbie question:

I've set up a MVC site, with a few controllers.  Now my site also has a lot of content files, which are stored in a network of subfolders within my web site, and I need to be able to access them directly, e.g.

```
http://mydomain.com/Content/Images/Geography/Asia/Japan/TokyoAtNight.jpg
```

Is there a way to make this a direct pass-through to the content folder, as specified by the path, or do I have to make a `Content` controller that interprets the rest of the URL and returns the file as some kind of `ActionResult`?  Bear in mind, of course, that there will be lots of different content types, not just JPEGs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use custom routing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982140/asp-net-mvc-custom-routing-long-custom-route-not-clicking-in-my-head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work without you doing anything - static files are not processed by the routing engine.

Comment: I agree. The other answers and comments seem to have misunderstood the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into Routing, and IgnoreRoute specifically. Here are a couple of places to start.

[Asp.Net Routing: How do I ignore multiple wildcard routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302/asp-net-routing-how-do-i-ignore-multiple-wildcard-routes)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the @Url.Content() helper method.

```
Url.Content("~Content/Images/Geography/Asia/Japan/TokyoAtNight.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The `IRouteHandler` and the route registration in your `global.asax` is your extensibility point for configuring how MVC handles url paths.

However, by default ASP.NET MVC will allow you to access image files directly, without any additional configuration.